# Why does HTMX swap fail on anchor tag?

Tags: html, htmx

I am trying to make an anchor tag update a part of my webpage using the HTMX library. I proceeded to make my anchor tag. The GET request is being executed however the html swap fails. Instead of swapping the contents of the target element, what happens is that the whole result is being displayed in the viewport. How can I fix this so that when I click on my anchor tag, the contents of the response is swapped in the element with the generator id?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `hx-boost="true"` attribute if you don't want to do a [boosting request](https://htmx.org/docs/#boosting) and replace `href` attribute with `hx-get`. The boosting request updates browser history as well, maybe something in your dev environment interfere with it, and forwards the browser to the partial's URL endpoint.

Furthermore the `hx-vals` must be valid JSON string (input of [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)), that uses quotation marks. You have to put quotation marks around the `{{ value }}` as well:

```
<a hx-get="{% ... %}"
   hx-target="#generator"
   hx-swap="innerHTML"
   hx-vals='{"report_name": "{{ value }}"}'
> {{ value }}</a>
```

Comment: Any tip on how to see what might be interfering with it?

Comment: Maybe you can see it in the browser's dev console's network tab. For example an automatic reload on code change issued by a JS dev server. Since the URL has been updated in the browser history (because of the `hx-boost`) the reload actually will load the partial's URL.

Comment: Hmm can't see anything in the network tab other than the request that the link ends up issuing

Comment: What HTMX version do you have?

Comment: Version htmx 1.6.1

Comment: That should be good even with `hx-boost`. Anyways, have you tried my suggestion? And where is the `#generator` target in your template?

Comment: Yea, removed the hx-boost but did not do anything. The #generator is a div located somewhere down the same page.

Comment: Let's look at the backend then. Could you please share the view function of `standard_report_setup` endpoint and all of the templates it uses to render the partial response?

Comment: I don't see what the back-end has to do with this. That part is behaving as expected and is returning what I would expect. The problem is somewhere on the front-end part of the code.

Comment: Right. After you remove the `hx-boost` could you also replace the `href` attribute with `hx-get`? I missed this earlier, but its is a required modification.

Comment: I actually tried that but then the link becomes unclickable entirelly

Comment: You can still click on it. Later just define a class with `cursor: pointer;` to force the pointer cursor type on these elements.

Comment: Ah ok, if that's the case then clicking on it doesn't trigger the hx-get at all even if I specify hx-trigger="click"

Comment: Found another issue: the `hx-vals` must be valid JSON string. See my updated answer. Hope this finally solves the problem.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the issue, even with the hx-vals completelly removed the action request does not trigger at all.

Comment: Don't think the issue is in the way I make the link anymore. I tried the same link on a different page and it worked. Something in the javascript code must be altering the behavior of the link.